# Differences between OvS with DPDK and without DPDK

Tags: networking

I need your help - I want to see difference between using DPDK and without DPDK.. For now, I tested my link (1G) using netperf.. I changed packet size on netperf, I increased the packet size gradually from 64 bytes to 1024 but still receive the same throughput(~940Mbps).. What is wrong with that? I expect to observed that with increase in packet size the throughput goes on increasing in the absence of Intel DPDK for a physical machine..
Do you have any idea how to test it properly to see any difference? Please, help me with that because for now I don't have any idea..

To sum up, for now I don't see the need of using DPDK if I have full throughput on my 1G link (940Mbps) but I HAVE TO test it..so I need to see difference between that. maybe you'll have any idea?

Comment: Why not read the documents at http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/communications/data-plane-development-kit.html ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO DPDK is mostly used, tested and tuned for packet processing & forwarding. So a common simple network benchmark is somewhat on the edge of what this kind of racing car is optimized for.

Due to that specialized nature e.g. apps that do routing + special features - many tests often go for complex setups and include e.g. expensive traffic generators.

I must admit, that sometimes I wanted a simpler test as well and to some extend you can do it. I've for example compared a (most simple) Openvswitch setup with two KVM guests to the same setup with Openvswitch-DPDK.

In that case you can run Traffic East/West (Guest to Guest) or North/South (External to Guest). It can depend a lot on mimimal tuning, but I was able to show improvements with the following "normal" benchmarks:
Netperf - very small packets
Netper - 8k packets
Uperf - very small packets
Uperf - 8k packets
Uperf - very small packets, many connections

But for example no improvement as it was good before with:
Uperf - 8k packets, many connections
Iperf - single or multiple conenctions

The amount is different, but to some extend that was true for E-W and N-S connections. But be careful Host-Guest seems to be special and at least had issues in my cases.

The TL;DR to take away is: if the normal networking stack already is fast, you can't win a lot - and in fact you loose some due to being less efficient, so try cases where the normal Linux stack is slow.

All this is opensource and so is the work we do on it, so while my Tests are totally WIP (and atm not my prio1 to maintain) and might change a lot you might get some inspiration or even base your test on [mine](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-server/ubuntu/+source/dpdk-testing/+git/dpdk-testing). I've uploaded some [results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23547387/) generated by that in September on Yakkety for you => http://paste.ubuntu.com/23547387/. One release earlier I used an older version of it to create the numbers for my [blog](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/05/05/the-new-simplicity-to-consume-dpdk/)

P.S. as you can expect there are also degradations so as with all tuning - know your workload!

Answer (score 0):

Data Plane Development Kit (DPDK) is used to accelerate the packet processing capacity. With plain OVS we can’t achieve much throughput as packet has to pass from user space and kernel space both.  In DPDK we can skip kernel space latency part.

Each processor socket has multiple cores. Each core has its private L1 cache memory, L2 cache memory and shared LLC (Last level cache) after that it will go to main memory (RAM).

So the point is when you use DPDK with OVS, you will be having less latency hence more throughput.

Answer (score 0):

On a 1Gbps NIC and the right CPU, ovs vs ovs-dpdk will not show much difference for the basic port to port forwarding testing. But one 10gbps, 25Gbps, 40Gbps and 100Gbps OVS (kernel bridge) forwarding vs OVS-DPDK (userspace bridge) forwarding because impactful because DPDK-OVS mitigates the performance issue by

1. reducing copy between port forwarding
2. Since there is a simple port to port forward the Exact Match Table is added to the flow cache table which makes lookup and action faster.
3. With `hw-offload=true` the 32 bit Match ID returns the entry in the action table eliminating the need for a cache table.

Note:

1. Based on the link speed the number of packets per size varies [[packet size and mpps](http://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_21_05_Intel_NIC_performance_report.pdf)
2. Enabling functions like rate-limit, tunnel termination on OVS will lead to packet processing difference higher comparing OVS to OVS-DPDK.

***Hence the observation simple port to port forwarding Ovs and Ovs-dpdk holds true for 1Gbps with various packet size as the number of packets are not stressed.***